# Speeding up this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This query currently takes about 30 seconds to run.

I'd like some help speeding it up, but don't know how to go about doing it. Any help would be fantastic. Please Note: I'm unable to make any actual changes to the database or it's design at this time.

```
SELECT top 1 v.[address], v.[address2], v.[city], v.[state_prov_id],v.[postcode],
        v.[first_name], v.[last_name], v.[client_specific_id], v.[name], v.phone,
        v.Location_id, v.Contact_id, v.Event_ID, v.client_id, v.program_id,
        v.source_code_id, v.file_source_code_id, v.URL, v.ScriptFrame,
        v.calldatemark, v.NumCallMark + 1 as Numcallmark,
        v.NumCallMarkDay + 1 as NumCallMarkDay,
        v.NumCallMarkWeek + 1 as NumCallMarkWeek, v.autoaudio,
        v.autohumantext, v.automachinetext 
   FROM vw_locationcontactdialer v 
  WHERE v.program_id = 10001565
    and v.numcallmark < 3 
    and (dateadd(hh,72,v.calldatemark) < getdate()
        or v.calldatemark = '01/01/1900' or v.calldatemark is null) 
    and  source_code_id = 10015311 
    and v.contact_id not in ( select contact_ID from CALL_HISTORY with (NOLOCK) 
                               where program_ID = 10001565 
                                 and result_id not in ('8','U','N')
                               group by contact_ID)
  order by calldatemark
```

I was given a tip to try and do a JOIN, but I'm unsure how I would accomplish this. I'm not sure how to do a JOIN and make sure that all contact_id's not in the subquery is accomplished.

I came up with this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 v.[address], v.[address2], v.[city], v.[state_prov_id],v.[postcode],
            v.[first_name], v.[last_name], v.[client_specific_id], v.[name],
            v.phone, v.Location_id, v.Contact_id, v.Event_ID, v.client_id,
            v.program_id, v.source_code_id, v.file_source_code_id, v.URL,
            v.ScriptFrame, v.calldatemark,
            v.NumCallMark + 1 as Numcallmark,
            v.NumCallMarkDay + 1 as NumCallMarkDay,
            v.NumCallMarkWeek + 1 as NumCallMarkWeek, v.autoaudio,
            v.autohumantext, v.automachinetext 
  from vw_locationcontactdialer v 
  JOIN CALL_HISTORY ch on v.Contact_ID = ch.contact_ID
 where v.Program_ID = 10001565
   and v.NumCallMark < 3
   and (DATEADD(hh,72,v.calldatemark) < GETDATE() 
        or v.CallDateMark = '01/01/1900' or v.CallDateMark is null)
   and v.Source_Code_ID = 10015311
   and ch.result_ID not in ('8','U','N')
 group by ch.contact_id
 order by v.CallDateMark
```

but it's not working because of this error, which I don't fully understand: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'vw_locationcontactdialer.address' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: If you get help on this question, is this query going to end up badgering people via telephone?

Comment: Without information about the view vw_locationcontactdialer and the underlying schema, it's going to be tough.

Comment: For a quick fix when trying to tweak the execution plan (but should probably not stay in the production code), replace `JOIN CALL_HISTORY ch ON ...` with `JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Contact_ID FROM CALL_HISTORY WHERE <all conditions on the ch table>) ch ON ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this into a join as follows:

```
from vw_locationcontactdialer v left outer join
     (select contact_ID
      from CALL_HISTORY with (NOLOCK) 
      where program_ID = 10001565 and 
            result_id not in ('8','U','N')
      group by contact_ID
     ) ch
     on v.contact_id = vh.contact_id
where . . .
      ch.contact_id is null
order by calldatemark
```

(Apologies, I get an error if I try to post the entire query.)

To make this work better, though, you probably want to go back to your original query and use a correlated subquery:

```
where
      not exists (select 1
                  from CALL_HISTORY ch with (NOLOCK) 
                  where program_ID = 10001565 and 
                        result_id not in ('8','U','N') and
                        ch.contact_id = v.contact_id
                 )
```

It woudl then help if you had an index on CALL_HISTORY.Contact_Id.  Even better, a multipart  index on Call_History encompassing contact_id, result_id, and program_id.

Comment: My apologies Gordon, but do you know why it would work better if I used a correlated subquery?

Comment: Because in the `join` case, the SQL engine summarize *all* the data by `contact_id`.  You seem to be looking for a small subset, so the correlated subquery is likely to be more efficient.  If you were returning data on all/many records, then the `join` might be better.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to accept the answer, I was doing some testing on it in our production server and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I can give you one small hint: The clause "(DATEADD(hh,72,v.calldatemark) < GETDATE()" prevents an index on the calldatemark field from getting used. 
It might help to replace it by "v.calldatemark < DATEADD(hh,-72,GETDATE())".

Also, ignore the "group by". You're only interested in certain contact_Ids. if the result of the subselect contains only a few entries, you will not gain any performance when converting this into a JOIN.

As the comments already say, you should examine and eventually post the schema of the underlying view as it might be the root cause for the bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a way to get this working right, and here's my code:

```
Select top 1 v.[address], v.[address2], v.[city], v.[state_prov_id], v.[postcode], 
v.[first_name], v.[last_name], v.[client_specific_id], v.[name], 
v.phone, v.Location_id, v.Contact_id, v.Event_ID, v.client_id, v.program_id,
v.source_code_id, v.file_source_code_id, v.URL, v.ScriptFrame, v.calldatemark,
v.NumCallMark + 1 as Numcallmark, 
v.NumCallMarkDay + 1 as NumCallMarkDay, 
v.NumCallMarkWeek + 1 as NumCallMarkWeek, v.autoaudio, 
v.autohumantext, v.automachinetext 
from vw_locationcontactdialer v 
left join (select contact_id from CALL_HISTORY 
where program_ID = 10001565 and result_ID not in ('8','U','N') 
group by contact_ID) h on v.Contact_ID = h.contact_ID 
where v.program_id = 10001565 
and v.numcallmark < 3 and (dateadd(hh,72,v.calldatemark) < getdate() 
or v.calldatemark = '01/01/1900' or v.calldatemark is null) 
and  source_code_id = 10015311  
and h.contact_ID is null order by calldatemark
```